# Adding categories to cystom post type

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add the possibility to add categories to the custom post type I've created in my Wordpress installation.

http://pastebin.com/DJRQvTxw

But it's not showing up as an option under that post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added custom posttype with lower case letter

```
register_post_type( 'programmering' , $args );
```

While creating its categories you have mentioned the with uppercase

```
 register_taxonomy( 'Programmering_category', 'Programmering', $args );
```

**i.e Programmering**

Try this one

```
 register_taxonomy( 'programmering_category', 'programmering', $args );
```

Comment: Question: I can't get any category ID's when creating categories within the new post type. var_dump(get_categories()) generates an empty array.

Comment: Post a new question and add all the information and problems you faced with the code